# Downloading not started after windows.open()

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, spring-mvc

I have controller where I generate and download the file.
When user clicks "Download" button, this code is executed:

```js
_statusWindow = window.open('downloadCSV', "_statusWindow");
_statusWindow.document.write('<div>  Please wait while we processing your request</div>');
_statusWindow.document.title = "Downloading...";
```

It points to controller downloadCSV, that generates file (without returning any views)
So new window is open, when file is generated - downloading starts automatically and window will be closed once downloading is finished. 
This code works fine, when I dont have this single line:

```
_statusWindow.document.write('<div>  Please wait while we processing your request</div>');
```

But I want to append this line to show the message to user.
WITH this line (as I show you in first code snippet), it starts downloading ONLY IF I click on button TWICE! And I have no idea why. When I click once - its just show the message, without calling controller and generating file, When I call it for second time - it's starts downloading...

Any suggestions, please HELP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you give it a try, I am trying to open download as a iframe, and closing the window on load of iframe.. hope it may work..

```
 var win = window.open("","_statusWindow");
 var html = '<html><head><title>Base</title></head><body>Please wait while 
   we processing your request...</body></html>';
 var iframe = win.document.createElement('iframe');
 iframe.src = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(html);
 win.document.body.appendChild(iframe);
 var iframe2 = win.document.createElement('iframe');
 iframe2.src = "downloadCSV";
 iframe2.onload= win.close();
 win.document.body.appendChild(iframe2);
```

Answer (score 1):

I doubt whether the message stays on the window or not until the download finishes, can you please give a try of the below code..

```
var win = window.open("","_statusWindow");
var html = '<html><head></head><body>Please wait while we processing your 
request...</body></html>';
var iframe = win.document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.src = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(html);
iframe.onload = window.open("downloadCSV","_statusWindow");
win.document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much 
But I want to close this window, after downloads is finished. I tried:
$(win.document).ready(win.close());
but It close the window right away. I thought this would work, because when  I downloading smth, I have spinner in top left corner of browser tab, so document is still NOT Ready. 
But it does not work. Do you have any suggestion how to close the tab when downloading is done? In my example, window is closing automatically when download is finished